# Vieta's formula for $f(\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

> Let $f(x)$ be a monic cubic polynomial. Let the solutions of the equation $f(\frac{1}{x})=0$ be $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$. If $\alpha+\beta+\gamma = 10$ and $\alpha\beta\gamma=15$, what is $\left \lceil{f(10)-f(-10)}\right \rceil$?

So since $f(x)$ is a monic cubic we can write it as $f(x) = x^3+bx^2+cx+d$ and from here $f(\frac{1}{x}) = \frac{1}{x^3} + b \frac{1}{x^2} + c \frac{1}{x}+d$.

The question stated that $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ were solutions for $f(\frac{1}{x})$ and I see that this would imply to use Vieta's here, but how do we go about it with something like $f(\frac{1}{x})$?

Comment: $f(x) = x(x^2 + bx + c + \frac{d}{x})$ and $f(\frac{1}{x}) = \frac{1}{x^3}(bx + cx^2 + dx^3 + 1)$?

Comment: Ah yes, but how can I factor a cubic like that? $f(x)$ should be a linear term multiplied with a quadratic?

Comment: A cubic factors like $(x-u)(x-v)(x-w)$. That is the standard factorization that *should* come to mind before any of the factorizations you just mentioned when one simply uses the word "factorization". It is also the kind of factorization used n Vieta's theorem, the exact theorem you mentioned...

Answer (score 1):

First notice that:
\begin{gather}
f(10)-f(-10) = 10^3+10^2b+10c+d - (-10)^3 - (-10)^2b-(-10)c -d =\\
=2000+20c
\end{gather}
So if we find the value of $c$ we are done.

As you noticed $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \frac{1}{x^3}(dx^3+cx^2+bx+1) = \frac{1}{dx^3}\left(x^3+\frac{c}{d}x^2+\frac{b}{d}x+\frac{1}{d}\right)$ where $d$ is different to zero because by hypotesis we have three solutions.

Thanks to Vieta's formula we have 
\begin{gather}
\frac{c}{d} = -(\alpha + \beta + \gamma) =-10\\
\frac{1}{d} =  -(\alpha\beta\gamma) -15
\end{gather}

Hence $c=\frac{2}{3}$ and the result is:
$$
f(10)-f(-10) =2000+20c = \frac{6040}{3}
$$

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't $\alpha\beta\gamma = -\frac{d}{a}$?

Comment: @Nate who is $a$? I used Vieta's formula for the polynomial $x^3 + \frac{c}{d}x^2 + \frac{b}{d}x + \frac{1}{d}$

Comment: Well in this case $a$ would simply be $1$? $a$ would be the coefficient of the cubic term, but since we have a monic it's $1$?

Comment: @Nate yes; if the polynomial is $ax^3+bx^2+cx+\tilde d = 0$, hence $\alpha\beta\gamma=-\frac{\tilde d}{a}$. In our case $a=1$ and $\tilde d = \frac{1}{d}$, so $-\frac{\tilde d}{a} = \frac{1}{d}$

Comment: @Nate tell me if you have other doubts

Comment: Oh I see! I would still have one question regarding the polynomial used to compute the result for Vieta's. Since you have factored out $\frac{1}{dx^3}$ is there a reason why we can use the expression inside $\frac{1}{dx^3}()$ for Vieta's and not the whole expression without $\frac{1}{dx^3}$ being factored out?

Comment: @Nate Vieta's formula works only for polynomial and $\frac{1}{dx^3}\left(x^3+\frac{c}{d}x^2+\frac{b}{d}x+\frac{1}{d}\right)$ is not; So we have to consider a polynomial with the same roots of $\frac{1}{dx^3}\left(x^3+\frac{c}{d}x^2+\frac{b}{d}x+\frac{1}{d}\right)$ and this is just the numerator: $x^3+\frac{c}{d}x^2+\frac{b}{d}x+\frac{1}{d}$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* You only need to find the coefficients of $f(x),$ then you would easily continue. To do this, note that the equation $f(1/x)=0$ simplifies to $$1+bx+cx^2+dx^3=0,$$ whence $$x^3+\frac cdx^2+\frac bdx+\frac 1d=0,$$ and we see that $$\alpha\beta\gamma=-\frac 1d=15,$$ from where $d=-1/15.$

Also, we see that $$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=-\frac cd=10\implies c=150.$$

Finally, note that you really don't need to know the coefficients of the even terms of $f(x)$ since they will vanish in a substitution of the form $f(x)-f(-x).$